# Regex to filter branches prefixed as release/

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci

For a Gitlab job I need a regex that matches all branches starting with `release/`.

For example:

1. `release/1`
2. `release/v1`
3. `release/v1.1`
4. `release/communityedition`

My job rule that's not working is:

```
myjob:
  image: mycustomimage
  stage: mystage
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^release\/'
```

Comment: `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^release\//'`. This is a typo-only question and I think it should be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `/^release\/'` into `/^release\//'`.

The `\` escapes the near `/`, so you must add an additional trailing `/`.